# Issue with score when we have two different types of fields

Tags: solr, lucene, similarity

In Solr I  have two fields as shown below:

```
   <field name="category_id" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" multiValued="true" />   
   <field name="event_attendance_mode" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" default="offline" />
```

while hitting query ? defType=edismax&fl=score,*&q=*:*&start=0&rows=10&bq=category_id:26^10 &bq=event_attendance_mode:online^100&debug=true

I am getting
"explain": {
"39505": "\n70.51515 = sum of:\n  1.0 = *:*\n  10.0 = category_id:[26 TO 26]^10.0\n  59.51515 = weight(event_attendance_mode:online in 9) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n    59.51515 = score(freq=1.0), product of:\n      100.0 = boost\n      1.3093333 = idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:\n        13 = n, number of documents containing term\n        49 = N, total number of documents with field\n      0.45454544 = tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:\n        1.0 = freq, occurrences of term within document\n        1.2 = k1, term saturation parameter\n        0.75 = b, length normalization parameter\n        1.0 = dl, length of field\n        1.0 = avgdl, average length of field\n",
"39506": "\n11.0 = sum of:\n  1.0 = *:*\n  10.0 = category_id:[26 TO 26]^10.0\n"
},

here issue is for field event_attendance_mode we are getting SchemaSimilarity calculation while for category_id we do not have this,so issue is when we have Schemasimilarity it calculate tf idf and then return the calculated score which is always less than the booosted value which we have passed(here it is "score": 70.51515) and when we do not have schemasimilarity it add the complete bosted value to score(here "score": 11). I wamt both field should be sync either both have tf/idf calculation else noone have this calcualtion. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Use a `string` field instead of `pint` field? If your goal is to boost by how unique the category is, that should work?

Comment: @MatsLindh, I dont want SchemaSimilarity applied on scores, as after applying Schemasimilarity if I am passing boosting as 100 score it will be around 52. I want score will also be same as boosting passed i.e 100 ... I found scehmasimilarity usually applies on string & text, is there is any other way out

Comment: Do not think of the actual score values having any significant meaning - it's only the relationship between the documents in the returned result that is important. _What_ do you want to affect the score? The only part I can see in your query that would give it 100 of anything is the online boost, and that will just be the same as sorting by the online field. Can you add a better example to your question of what you want to achieve?